# Combinar función Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

La función del siguiente código es que al digitar un `ITEM,` de los que aparece en el `switch,` me muestre el precio en `VALOR_RE_MO,` pero quiero que al ingresar un valor en `CANTIDAD` me multiplique el precio por esa cantidad ingresada. Este código hace eso por medio del evento`onkeyup,` pero no me sirve por que cada vez que paso el cursor se sigue multiplicando, quisiera poder hacerlo de forma automática después de ejecutar la primer función o tener las dos funciones dentro de una sola. También estuve revisando los CALLBACK, pero sinceramente no pude implementarlo.

```js
 function cargarSelect_tecnico1(valor){
  
        var txt = $('#VALOR_RE_MO');
  
        switch(valor)
        {
          case '':
            codigo= '';
            break;
        case 'ANCOL':
            codigo= '100';
            break;
        case 'UANCL':
            codigo= '200';
            break;
        case 'ARTEL':
            codigo= '300';
            break;
    
        }
       
      txt.value = codigo;
    }
    
function operacion(){
  
      cantidad = $('#CANTIDAD')[0];
      valor = $('#VALOR_RE_MO')[0];

      valor.onkeyup = function(e) {
          valor.value = parseInt(valor.value) * cantidad.value;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Item</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' 
    onkeyup='cargarSelect_tecnico1(this.value);' autofocus="autofocus"O></td>

    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' onkeyup="operacion();" 
    /></td>

    <label>Valor</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO'/></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @Andersson Viveros Martinez, lo que tienes que hacer es poner en `VALOR_RE_MO` el valor o `codigo` unitario cuando `CANTIDAD` esté vacío, te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
function cargarSelect_tecnico1(valor) {
    var codigo = '';
  
    switch(valor){
      case '':
          codigo = '';
      break;
      case 'ANCOL':
          codigo = '100';
      break;
      case 'UANCL':
          codigo = '200';
      break;
      case 'ARTEL':
          codigo = '300';
      break;

    }
    //Ponemos el 'VALOR_RE_MO' segun el 'ITEM'
    $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val(codigo);
    //No tenemos que ejecutar ahorita la función
    //operacion() ya que aun no hay una cantidad definida.
}

function operacion() {
    //Ejecutamos 'cargarSelector_tecnico1' para poner el valor
    //según el 'ITEM'.
    cargarSelect_tecnico1($('#ITEM').val().toUpperCase());
    var valor = parseInt( $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val() ),
        cantidad = parseInt( $('#CANTIDAD').val() );
    if(!isNaN( valor ) && !isNaN( cantidad )){
        $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val( valor * cantidad );
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Item</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' 
    onkeyup='cargarSelect_tecnico1(this.value.toUpperCase());' autofocus="autofocus"></td>

    <label>Cantidad</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' onkeyup="operacion();"
    /></td>

    <label>Valor</label>
    <td><input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO'/></td>
```

Espero y te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas volver a añadir un listener en la función `operacion`; aquí solo haz el cálculo y muéstralo en la caja de texto. Como consejo, usa mejor el evento `input` para que no se interprete el focus al hacer tab como un evento de tecla. Finalmente, llama también a `operacion` al escribir el código del producto en caso el resto de cajas estén llenas para proceder a un nuevo cálculo.

**Ejemplo**

```js
function cargarSelect_tecnico1(valor) {
  let codigo = '';
  switch (valor) {
    case '':
      codigo = '';
      break;
    case 'ANCOL':
      codigo = '100';
      break;
    case 'UANCL':
      codigo = '200';
      break;
    case 'ARTEL':
      codigo = '300';
      break;

  }

  $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val(codigo);
  operacion();
}

function operacion() {
  const valor = parseInt($('#VALOR_RE_MO').val());
  const cantidad = parseInt($('#CANTIDAD').val());

  if (isNaN(valor) || isNaN(cantidad)) {
    return;
  }

  $('#VALOR_RE_MO').val(valor * cantidad);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Item</label>
<td><input type="text" name="ITEM" id='ITEM' onkeyup='cargarSelect_tecnico1(this.value);' autofocus="autofocus" O></td>

<label>Cantidad</label>
<td><input type="text" name="CANTIDAD" id='CANTIDAD' onkeyup="operacion();" /></td>

<label>Valor</label>
<td><input type="text" name="VALOR_RE_MO" id='VALOR_RE_MO' /></td>
```

Comment: Hola te cuento que probé tu código pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, lo otro que no entiendo es lo del evento`input,` pues no se cual es o como se utiliza, me podrías explicar por favor.

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez tipea "ANCOL" en el item y te saldrá su precio, ahora escribe la cantidad y se actualizará automáticamente el valor. ¿No era eso lo que querías?